# How would we get the conditional distribution?

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

Having the marginal distributions, say $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, how would we get the conditional distribution $f(x|y)$? The relation is given by:
$$f(x)=\int f(x|y)f(y)dy$$ 
Do we need to find the derivatives of both sides and then solve a differential equation?!

Answer (score 3):

The marginals don't determine the conditional.

Indeed [copulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_%28probability_theory%29) are a way to have all manner of different joint distributions with given marginals